# Can Chromium features that are normally turned on via switches be turned on programatically after starting up?

Tags: electron, command-line-arguments, chromium

Is there a way to use Chromium switches *after* starting it up, or must they be enabled on start up? For example, can switches be passed to the renderer processes, or just to the main process?

I want to turn on paint flashing in Chromium (actually in my Electron app which runs on top of Chromium).

Devtools has a [checkbox](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/rendering-settings) that turns this on, but I want to be able to turn this on without devtools, and after the app has started.

I know there's a [`show-paint-rects`](https://github.com/chromium/chromium/search?q=show-paint-rects&unscoped_q=show-paint-rects) flag I can use:

```
chrome.exe --show-paint-rects
```

In my Electron app, I would need to use [`app.commandLine.appendSwitch`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/chrome-command-line-switches.md):

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("show-paint-rects");
```

*I also found a [`ui-show-paint-rects`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/66.0.3359.158/ui/compositor/compositor_switches.cc#30) flag that lives in something called the "compositor," but that may be irrelevant for me.*

Both of these work, but since Chromium uses a [multi-process architecture](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-architecture), I'm hoping that there's a way I can specify that switch, or otherwise, turn on a feature in one process and not have to specify it at startup.

Is there a way to do this in Chromium? (Would be ideal to do this in Electron, but I'm not counting on it)

Comment: depends. majority of flags are required to be set before whole choromium app instance starts, reason it only works via cli or electron's appendSwitch before app ready event.

Comment: @OJKwon Yeah, I know that in general in depends, but I'm interested in turning on paint flashing after startup. Maybe I should make my question more specific...

Comment: you can safely assume it won't unless there is specific comment about some flag can be enabled after chromium app starts.

Comment: @OJKwon Fair enough.. I was crossing my fingers